# Asymmetric behavior in ctx-solver-simplify

Tags: z3

I'm seeing rather surprising behavior from `ctx-solver-simplify`, where the order of parameters to z3.And() seems to matter, using the latest version of Z3 from the master branch of https://git01.codeplex.com/z3 (89c1785b):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import z3

a, b = z3.Bools('a b')
p = z3.Not(a)
q = z3.Or(a, b)
for e in z3.And(p, q), z3.And(q, p):
  print e, '->', z3.Tactic('ctx-solver-simplify')(e)
```

produces:

```
And(Not(a), Or(a, b)) -> [[Not(a), Or(a, b)]]
And(Or(a, b), Not(a)) -> [[b, Not(a)]]
```

Is this a bug in Z3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a bug. The tactic `ctx-solver-simplify` is very expensive and inherently asymmetric. That is, the order the sub-formulas are visited affect the final result. This tactic is implemented in the file `src/smt/tactic/ctx_solver_simplify_tactic.cpp`. The code is quite readable. Note that, it uses a "SMT" solver (`m_solver`), and makes several calls to `m_solver.check()` while traversing the input formula. Each one of these calls can be quite expensive. For particular problem domains, we can implement a version of this tactic that is even more expensive, and avoids the asymmetry described in your question.

**EDIT:**

You may also consider the tactic `ctx-simplify`, it is cheaper than `ctx-solver-simplify`, but it is symmetric. The tactic `ctx-simplify` will essentially applies rules such as:

```
A \/ F[A] ==> A \/ F[false]
x != c \/ F[x] ==> F[c]
```

Where `F[A]` is a formula that may contain `A`. It is cheaper than `ctx-solver-simplify` because it does not invoke a SMT solver when it is traversing the formula. Here is an example using this tactic (also available [online](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/Ghzz)):

```py
a, b = Bools('a b')
p = Not(a)
q = Or(a, b)
c = Bool('c')
t = Then('simplify', 'propagate-values', 'ctx-simplify')
for e in Or(c, And(p, q)), Or(c, And(q, p)):
  print e, '->', t(e)
```

Regarding humand-readability, this was never a goal when implementing any tactic. Please, tell us if the tactic above is not good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks!  If I want to produce a succinct human-readable version of a formula, and computation time is less important, is there an API or tactic I can invoke in Z3 that will "try harder" to simplify an expression?  Or do I need to modify ctx_solver_simplify_tactic.cpp / write my own tactic?

Comment: Indeed, `propagate-values` helps a lot in my case -- thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be better to write a custom tactic because there are 
other tradeoffs when you essentially ask for canonicity.
Z3 does not have any tactics that convert formulas into a canonical form.
So if you want something that always produces the same answer for formulas 
that are ground equivalent you will have to write a new normalizer that 
ensures this.

The ctx_solver_simplify_tactic furthermore makes some tradeoffs when simplifying formulas: 
it avoids simplifying the same sub-formula multiple times. If it did, it could increase
the size of the resulting formula significantly (exponentially).